# Radio Button with native-base and redux-form

Tags: react-native, redux-form

I am building a native react application with a multi-step form with redux-form and native base, I miss it more than the radio button but I can not adapt it to redux-form.

I did, however, with the native-base picker.

Could you give me an example of a radio button with native base and redux-form.